# JavaScript: Quick return if function returns null

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6

Is there a way to shorten this fragment of code?

```
const result = getResult();
if (!result) {
    return;
}

// Work with result
```

I keep having lots of these in my code and would love to do something like:

```
const result = getResult() || return;

// Work with result
```

**EDIT:**
I only want convertable inputs to be persisted.

```
const parseInput = (input: string): void => {
   const convertedInput = convert(input);
   if (!convertedInput) {
       return;
   }

   persist(convertedInput);
}
```

I know I could call the converter twice. But I want to avoid that:

```
const parseInput = (input: string): void => {
   if (!convert(input)) {
       return;
   }

   persist(convert(input));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is as good as it gets, however, if you want to experiment a bit with the functional style, you can wrap the value into a "monad", which would invoke attached functions only if the value is non-zero. Here's a toy implementation:

```
function maybe(x) {
    return {
        value: x,
        apply(fn) {
            if (this.value)
                this.value = fn(this.value)
            return this;
        }
    }
}
```

With this `maybe`, your example would look like:

```
const parseInput = input => maybe(convert(input)).apply(persist)
```

See the [Oliver's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56683804/989121) for a more serious approach.

Comment: Lodash should implement that function! :D

Answer (score 1):

You can do this

```
const result =  "default value" || getResult();
```

If getResult is null or not defined then you'll get `result` as "default value". If that's what you want

```js
function getResult() {
   return null;
}
const result =  "okay" || getResult();
console.log(result)
```

And when getResult is not defined you get

```js
const result =  "okay" || getResult();
console.log(result)
```

Basically, the syntax is

```
null || undefined || null || 0 || "okay" || "defined" // "okay"
```

It goes from left to right and picks the most relevant value

Comment: What if want to return then instead of having a default value? Would `const result =  return || getResult();` return before calling getResult() ?

Comment: Simply doing return; gives undefined [see here](https://jsfiddle.net/po1sL92u/) And that will give errors when you are working with it @Julisch To transform something in your previous comment to a valid syntax be `const result = undefined || getResult();`

Comment: See my EDIT please

Comment: Well, your edit doesn't change anything. You can still use my approach for a more readable and shortcode. Else there's no way to achieve what you want @Julisch

Comment: So I can only set a default value but not just return instantly if the function returns `null`?

Comment: What do you mean by _just return instantly_ ?? To return null? Undefined? String? @Julisch

Comment: I meant to abort the function without throwing an error. Just return early in a void function.

Comment: Then you should put your code in try and catch and catch any error. Which won't give any errors. @Julisch

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know if this answer will give you something that you'll be happy with, but it seems to me to present a potential solution to the problem of handling unknown results.

`Maybe`s are structures which have this kind of checking built-in. the `.map()` below will not be called if there is no value in the `Maybe`, so the code which consumes it does not need to check whether a value is present.

This does mean that you have to change the way in which you handle these values however, and, unless you want to write your own, it means using a library. As such this is hardly an ideal solution, but I hope it gives an option at least.

```js
const { None, Some } = Monet;

const getResult = () => Math.random() > 0.5
  ? None()
  : Some(1);

const test = getResult()
  .map(x => x + 2);
  
console.dir(test.val);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/monet@0.9.0/dist/monet.min.js"></script>
```